# npm start gives the error that server.js is not a valid win32 application

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to start the application server for a group project I'm doing.  I posted my error below and I'll copy the npm-debug.log contents below.

This works perfectly fine my teammates mac laptop.  I'm trying to run this on a Windows 8 64 bit machine.  I tried with both the 32 bit and 64 bit binaries of node and it gives the same output.

output from npm start

> Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All
>   rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\damien\Documents\GitHub\lend [development]> npm start
>
> > lending-app@0.0.1 start C:\Users\damien\Documents\GitHub\lend
> >     brunch watch --server
>
> 05 Apr 22:01:49 - error: couldn't load server lend.js: Error: %1 is
>   not a valid Win32 application.
>   C:\Users\damien\Documents\GitHub\lend\node_modules\client-sessions\node_modules\node-proxy\build\Release\nodeproxy.node
>
> C:\Users\damien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\brunch\lib\watch.js:105
>         if (server.startServer == null) {
>                   ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'startServer' of undefined
>       at startServer (C:\Users\damien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\brunch\lib\watch.js:105:17)
>       at C:\Users\damien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\brunch\lib\watch.js:418:18
>       at C:\Users\damien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\brunch\lib\helpers.js:475:14
>       at C:\Users\damien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\brunch\node_modules\read-components\index.js:207:16
>       at C:\Users\damien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\brunch\node_modules\read-components\index.js:34:14
>       at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:168:19)
>
> npm ERR! lending-app@0.0.1 start: `brunch watch --server` npm ERR!
>   Exit status 8 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the lending-app@0.0.1 start
>   script. npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the lending-app
>   package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that
>   this fails on your system: npm ERR!     brunch watch --server npm ERR!
>   You can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls lending-app npm
>   ERR! There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! System
>   Windows_NT 6.2.9200 npm ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"  "start" npm ERR!
>   cwd C:\Users\damien\Documents\GitHub\lend npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
>   npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Additional logging details can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\damien\Documents\GitHub\lend\npm-debug.log npm ERR! not ok
>   code 0 C:\Users\damien\Documents\GitHub\lend [development]>

npm-debug.log

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'start' ]
>
> 2 info using npm@1.4.3
>
> 3 info using node@v0.10.26
>
> 4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
>
> 5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
>
> 6 info prestart lending-app@0.0.1
>
> 7 info start lending-app@0.0.1
>
> 8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
>
> 9 info lending-app@0.0.1 Failed to exec start script
>
> 10 error lending-app@0.0.1 start: `brunch watch --server`
>
> 10 error Exit status 8
>
> 11 error Failed at the lending-app@0.0.1 start script.
>
> 11 error This is most likely a problem with the lending-app package,
>
> 11 error not with npm itself.
>
> 11 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> 11 error     brunch watch --server
>
> 11 error You can get their info via:
>
> 11 error     npm owner ls lending-app
>
> 11 error There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> 12 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
>
> 13 error command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program 
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
>
> 14 error cwd C:\Users\damien\Documents\GitHub\lend
>
> 15 error node -v v0.10.26
>
> 16 error npm -v 1.4.3
>
> 17 error code ELIFECYCLE
>
> 18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Not sure I get this, are you sure it's not supposed to be just `node lend.js`, why are you running npm start ?

Answer (score 0):

`npm start` calls the `scripts.start` entry in your package.json file.  In this case it looks like the command is `brunch watch --server`. Chances are you are missing the `brunch` binary which is causing npm to spit out the error.

Comment: I reinstalled brunch to be sure, and the output is the same.

Comment: what is the output if you call `brunch watch --server` manually from the same directory?